# Picture not vertically aligning?

Tags: html, image, html-table, vertical-alignment

I'm creating a registration form and I'm at the error handle'ing. I want to display a picture next to a textbox if the username is alredy taken.

```
<table width='60%'>
    <tr>
        <td align='left'>Username:</td>
        <td align='right' valign='center'>
            <img src='img/warning.png' title='Username alredy taken.' height='16px'
            />&nbsp;
            <input type='textbox' name='register_username' value='USERNAME'
            />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2RM8N/2/

As shown in the jsfiddle above, the picture doesn't get vertically aligned, I want it in the same vertical height as the text/textbox.

Answer (score 0):

`"valign"` property doesn't accept `"center"` value, you probably meant `"middle"`.

Try to apply this style to both the `INPUT` and `IMG` :

```
style="vertical-align: middle;"
```